# How to get search result output in uppercase in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

How to get output field in uppercase in MongoDB.

Consider below data set where we want to return output in upper case for a particular field(suppose filed ‘type')

data:

[image]

If we run the query it returns error as below failed to parse, please suggest a solution to get field 'type' output in upper case. 
db.products.find([{$toUpper:”type”},{type:”wall”}])

Answer (score 1):

You need to use aggregation and project the value given from toUpper as a new field.  See the example from the [$toUpper documentation page](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toUpper/):

```
db.inventory.aggregate(
   [
     {
       $project:
         {
           item: { $toUpper: "$item" },
           description: { $toUpper: "$description" }
         }
     }
   ]
)
```

Notice how the result of $toUpper is used as the value of a new field item.

Try this with your data.  I created a test collection and it worked for me.

```
db.products.aggregate(
   {
      $match: {
         "type": "wall"
      }
   },
   {
      $project: {
         "upperCaseType": {
            $toUpper: "$type"
         }
      }
   }
);
```

The match verifies the `type` is "wall" and the projection says to only include the value of the `type` field in upper case.  There may be a way to do this without aggregation, but I'm not aware of it.

Comment: No problem!  Please don't forget to accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    db.products.find({ "name": { $regex: "abc" } });
```

we can use $regex operator for finding text uppercase or lowercase both.